# Submitting a JavaScript Array to JSP

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, jsp

I am developing a webapp, it connects to some other website over a JS API.
I want to use an array of JSON-Objects I get from this API in my Java Application.

Is there a possibility to submit the array, e.g. with a form?

Cheers Dominik

Comment: Why don't you connect to the other site from your server application?

Comment: There is only a JS API available. Or is there a possibility to use that from the server application?

Comment: Huh? There is an API, use it. The exchange data format does not limit you in the choice of your programming language.

Comment: To use the API I have to include a JavaScript file into my html and call some functions in that. I dont know how to do that in Java, maybe I misunderstand something...

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new array
- Create a loop
- Use [JSON.stringify](http://cjihrig.com/blog/native-browser-support-for-json-part-2-of-2/) on the current index in the loop
- Push the string into the new array
- After the loop, use join() to stringify the new array
- Copy the new string into a hidden form field
- Submit